# Repeater Asp.net Button Onclick Call C# Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i have asp.net Repeater which  repeate 3 controls using to insert into database 
`textbox` name `textbox` code 
and `button` to insert this into database using entity Model 
i have the method how to call it with each item ?

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate >
         <div>
             <div    id="outer" style=" background-color:lightblue  "><center><%# Eval("LangaugeName")%> </center></div> 
              <div    id="LangId" style="display :none  "><center><%# Eval("LangId")%> </center></div> 
             <br />
             <br />
    <div class="text-center">
        <strong>Zone Name&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="TxtZoneName" style="width: 295px" type="text" runat ="server" />
    </div>
    <div ><br /></div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <strong>Zone Code&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="txtZoneCode" style="width: 295px" type="text" runat ="server"  />

</div>
   <div class="text-center">
        <br />
       &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" style=" background-color :azure   " />
        <br />
        <br />
   </div>

</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: what you want to do? insert each row record in db table on row button click?

Comment: yes @yogi970 you right

Comment: and is there any specific need to use HTML controls?Why are you not using asp.net controls?

Comment: if it is purely insert command then why are you using a repeater for displaying textbox and button, you can directly put two textbox and one button on page to insert record in db..

Comment: i need insert this record with multi languages !